# Cassandra: need to migrate cassandra to log4j

Tags: cassandra, log4j2

We are using embedded cassandra in our groovy test cases, we are migrating from logback to log4j2.  Whenever i run the groovy test which uses cassandra it gives an exception of NoClassDefFoundError for ch/qos/logback /classic /Logger. I have excluded logback dependency from all existing  cassandra dependency  still its looking for logback.  How should i make cassandra log using log4j2

Comment: what has this to do with [embedded]?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra isn't setup or designed to run embedded so while there might be some hacks that can get you by it will be something difficult to keep working across versions.

I would recommend using ccm for your tests to run it out of jvm and it will also give you more control for interesting configurations. The java driver has a useful bridge for java applications in their tests here: [CCMBridge.java](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4123fa31bfcb8e8afb4418e1647c2d69aa6c4ec8/driver-core/src/test/java/com/datastax/driver/core/CCMBridge.java)

Longterm you might be able to use something [CASSANDRA-14821](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14821) as there will be native connections exposed and give you a lot more control over results of queries and such.